# Expressing a natural number as the sum of multiples of 2 other natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that any given natural number $N$ can be expressed as the sum of multiples of 2 given natural numbers, $K_1$ and $K_2$, if and only if $N$ is divisible by the HCF of $K_1$ and $K_2$.

The "only if" part is easy to show. However, I was not able to show the "if" part or find any counterexample against it.

Any hints?

Comment: Cf. [Bezout's lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma)

Comment: Are the multiples **positive** multiples? Otherwise, $3$ is **not** the sum of **positive** multiples of $2$ and $5$ although the HCF of $2$ and $5$ is $1$ and $1$ divides $3$. If you don't mean that, please edit your question to explicitly mention integer multiples.

Comment: @Somos Yes, I meant to say a number $N$ greater than both $K_1$ and $K_2$ being expressed as the sum of non-negative multiples of $K_1$ and $K_2$. Did not think about the possibility of negative multiples.

Comment: But that is not enough. Read  the Wikipedia article [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) for counter-examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HCF of the two number $K_1$ and $K_2$ can be expressed as $aK_1+bK_2$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ by Bezout's lemma. Hence if $N=m*HCF(K_1,K_2)$, then $N=m*(aK_1+bK_2)=maK_1+mbK_2$!